# Python Script runs on terminal/shell but not when executed from a function

Tags: python-3.8

I have a Python script that takes a JSON argument.

When I run this script from the terminal/shell it runs. Here is the exact code that I execute on the terminal

```
python  bot.py dca strin '{\"marketplace\":\"USDT\",\"tokenlist\":[{\"token\":\"C98\",\"min\":0,\"max\":500},{\"token\":\"CHESS\",\"min\":1,\"max\":5}],\"compression\":1,\"buyamount\":20,\"tp\":3,\"sl\":10,\"continueflag\":0,\"rsi_level\":0,\"trstart\":1.5,\"trstop\":0.1,\"dca\":[[2,100],[4,100],[6,100],[8,100],[10,100],[15,100]],\"host\":\"localhost\",\"user\":\"root\",\"password\":\"root\",\"database\":\"trading\"}'
```

My error comes when I create another Python script/function to execute my bot.py.

In my function, I execute the bot.py using the subprocess.call as shown below.

```
args = '{\"marketplace\":\"USDT\",\"tokenlist\":[{\"token\":\"C98\",\"min\":0,\"max\":500},{\"token\":\"CHESS\",\"min\":1,\"max\":5}],\"compression\":1,\"buyamount\":20,\"tp\":3,\"sl\":10,\"continueflag\":0,\"rsi_level\":0,\"trstart\":1.5,\"trstop\":0.1,\"dca\":[[2,100],[4,100],[6,100],[8,100],[10,100],[15,100]],\"host\":\"localhost\",\"user\":\"root\",\"password\":\"root\",\"database\":\"trading\"}'
subprocess.call(["python", "\\bot_5_12/runner_single.py dca strin", args])
```

However, when I execute my function I get the error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Kindly advise because I do not know how to debug this from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to replace quotes ( ' to " ), like this :

```
args = "{\"marketplace\":\"USDT\",\"tokenlist\":[{\"token\":\"C98\",\"min\":0,\"max\":500},{\"token\":\"CHESS\",\"min\":1,\"max\":5}],\"compression\":1,\"buyamount\":20,\"tp\":3,\"sl\":10,\"continueflag\":0,\"rsi_level\":0,\"trstart\":1.5,\"trstop\":0.1,\"dca\":[[2,100],[4,100],[6,100],[8,100],[10,100],[15,100]],\"host\":\"localhost\",\"user\":\"root\",\"password\":\"root\",\"database\":\"trading\"}"

args = str(args).replace(" ","")

subprocess.call(["python", "\\bot_5_12/runner_single.py dca strin", args])
```

Test your JSON [right here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#).

Comment: I tried it with the double quotes and it still brings up the same error.

Comment: Try to remove spaces from JSON using : str(args).replace(" ","")